# When I type "libvirtd --listen" in linux shell, there is error "GNUTLS support not available in this build"

Tags: libvirt, virsh

I was doing some experiment on live migration using virsh. When I input anything related to **tls**, such as "# virsh -c qemu+tls://source/system",or "libvirtd --listen", there would be errors like "GNUTLS support not available in this build". So, here is what I tried to fix it:

1. Reinstall libvirt with `--with-gnutls`

   ```
   #yum install gnutls-devel
   #sh ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libdir=/usr/lib64 --with-gnutls
   ```
2. After it successfully installed, reload it

   ```
   # systemctl daemon-reload
   # systemctl restart libvirtd
   ```

then I tried again my experiment, still there are errors "GNUTLS support not available in this build".

Any hints helpful will be appreciated sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

Create TLS certificate first, follow the instruction on libvirt official website. Then reinstall libvirt again, everything goes right.